# Post your easiest and hardest Questions and Answers!

Tags: discussion

We have a little less than a month before our two-year anniversary, so I thought we might do a fun little activity: post your most basic and most advanced questions and answers.  This serves two purposes: First, it encourages people to read questions and answers they otherwise might not read.  And second, it gives us all an opportunity to look over our old questions and answers and see if they require improvement.

I have a large number of questions and answers, so I've included five in each category, but if others want to post a smaller number, that's fine too.

EDIT: To clarify, what I meant by easy and hard is easy or hard for the typical reader to understand, i.e. basic and advanced.

Comment: Nice idea for second anniversary.

Comment: How about adding questions or answers they like the most (asked or answered by them)?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Well, let's not complicate this thread with too many different criteria.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan why have you made the post community-wiki? **Anyone** can edit [**your**](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/567/277) list of question & answer!

Comment: @Pandya I did it to try to disable voting (which is pretty meaningless in a question like this), but it didn't have intended effect.

Comment: Interesting idea, will post mine :)

Answer (score 6):

Five Easiest Questions:

[Do any scriptures say that the hunter Jara was a rebirth of Vali?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7397/36)

[What scriptures describe the story of Krishna killing Ekalavya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8028/36)

[How did Dasharatha become friends with Jatayu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3044/36)

[When was Ravana hit by the Sudarshana Chakra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2187/36)

[What scriptures discuss why the sky appears blue?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9984/36)

Five Hardest Questions:

[What is the Advaita argument for why causes can't have real existence?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12109/36)

[Has anyone responded to Ramanujacharya's refutation of the Cosmological Argument for the existence of God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11118/36)

[What is the Nyaya argument for Karma being the instrumental cause of the Universe?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6912/36)

[What is Ramanujacharya's argument that the Upanishads must be true if they grant Moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11143/36)

[Do the Aitareya and Brihadaranyaka Upanishads correctly interpret two hymns of Vamadeva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4050/36)

Five Easiest Answers:

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/924/36

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2876/36

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/942/36

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2086/36

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6812/36

Five Hardest Answers:

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5474/36

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8716/36

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2958/36

Comment: Keshav! How finding Jara as rebirth of Vali is easiest question? None has answered it till now.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Well, as I said in my question it's about your most basic and most advanced posts, i.e. how easy it is for the typical reader to understand it.  Vali being reborn as Jara is a common thing that most Hindus know, or think they know.  So it's easy for a reader to understand.  It's the same reason I included Dasharatha being friends with Jatayu and Krishna killing Ekalavya.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: ohh. I thought it was about finding answer.

Comment: @TheDestroyer OK, then you may want to edit your list.

Answer (score 4):

Five Easiest Questions

[Do animals know God exists?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8441/3500)

[What scriptures say that Lord Shiva sits in Smashan (Cremation Grounds)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9782/3500)

[Which verse of Sri Rudram of Yajurveda has the word “Shiva”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10818/3500)

[Supreme Brahman in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8527/3500)

[Can Shaivaites or Devotees of Shiva eat meat?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8362/3500)

Five Hardest Questions

[Wherein Aithreya Brahmana of Rig Veda has the word “Telugu”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11111/3500)

[What Scriptures other than Ramayana describe Vishwamitra cursing his sons?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11566/3500)

[How ॐ (OM) is written in Brahmi Script?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11640/3500)

[Story of Lord Vishnu's sword Nandaka?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8664/3500)

[How does artificial confluence of Rivers differ from natural confluence of Rivers?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8611/3500)

Five Easiest Answers

[Legend behind origin of Vayu Lingam in Srikalahasti and its meaning](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10824/3500)

[Did Lord Shiva and Lord Rama ever meet in person?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11074/3500)

[What are all Varaha Avatars of Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10983/3500)

[Will Parashurama reappear in Kaliyuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10672/3500)

[Where is it mentioned that Krishna and Rama Worshipped Shiva Lingam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9995/3500)

Five Hardest Answers

[Did lord Brahma commit incest with his daughter?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11622/3500)

[Why didn't lord Hanuman help Sugriva to kill Vali?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11668/3500)

[What is the reason behind lokas in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10322/3500)

[Concept of Immortals in Hindusim?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10768/3500)

[Why are Yama temples few in number?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11812/3500)

Questions i like the most.

[Why Bharata Varsha (India) alone is called Karma Bhoomi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10977/3500)

[Are there any references to Gravity in Hindu Scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9102/3500)

[Will Brahmachari's (life long bachelors) get moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8929/3500)

[What exactly happens during Parakaya Pravesha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10374/3500)

[How did the serpent Adisesha become bed for Lord Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9404/3500)

Answers which i like the most

[Why Lord Shiva is depicted as Lord of Time?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9290/3500) (My all time favorite answer on this site.)

[How qualities of humans change drastically from Kali Yuga to Satya Yuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9205/3500)

[Why did Vyasa depict different Supreme Gods in different Puranas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11077/3500)

[Ashvatthaman's immortality?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11089/3500)

[Who is Rudra deva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9923/3500)

Answer (score 4):

Basic Questions:

- [What is difference between Shruti and Smriti?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8591/277)
- [What is Raj-yoga? Is it related to Jnana-Yoga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9043/277)
- [What is Adhyatma (spiritual)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11531/277)
- [What are the Agama scripture?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12282/277)
- [What are Avidya, Maya and Ignorance?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9448/277)

Advance Questions:

- [Differences between Advaita & Vishishtadvaita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12272/277)
- [What is Turiya and how can we realize it?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10738/277)
- [Merge of Karma & Bhakti into Jnana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11738/merge-of-karma-bhakti-into-jnana)
- [Why does Krishna consider/believe the devotee who worship him as saguna superior than who worship as nirguna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11520/277)

Interesting Questions:

- [The concept of God in Bhakti Yoga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9044/the-concept-of-god-in-bhakti-yoga)
- [What is (if any) the significance of Ignorance/Maya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8890/277)

Basic Answers:

- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10560/277
- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9164/277
- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9981/277
- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11532/277
- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9957/277

Advance Answers:

- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11078/277
- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11182/277
- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11748/277
- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11897/277

Answer (score 3):

**Five Easiest Questions**

[What is the shape of Earth according to Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12365/what-is-the-shape-of-earth-according-to-hindu-scriptures)

[At what age did Shri Krishna leave Vrindavan?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12173/at-what-age-did-shri-krishna-leave-vrindavan)

[Translation of the very first Shloka of the Rig Veda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/translation-of-the-very-first-shloka-of-the-rig-veda)

[Where can I find an online version of the Adhyatma Ramayana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11906/where-can-i-find-an-online-version-of-the-adhyatma-ramayana)

[Why did Shalya fight on the side of the Kauravas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11807/why-did-shalya-fight-on-the-side-of-the-kauravas)

**Five Hardest Questions**

[How is the position of Surya and Chandra related to Amavasya and Poornima?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12083/how-is-the-position-of-surya-and-chandra-related-to-amavasya-and-poornima)

[Examples on the flexibility of Varna in ancient times](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12081/examples-on-the-flexibility-of-varna-in-ancient-times)

[Rashi in Jyotisha - Sirodaya, Prushtodaya and Ubhayodaya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12124/rashi-in-jyotisha-sirodaya-prushtodaya-and-ubhayodaya)

[Smaller cycles of Kaala or Time](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11779/smaller-cycles-of-kaala-or-time)

[What is the relationship between cause and effect as enunciated by Maharishi Kanada?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12064/what-is-the-relationship-between-cause-and-effect-as-enunciated-by-maharishi-kan)

**Five Easiest Answers**

[Does chanting Holy Names while doing worldly duties generate any punya karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8459/does-chanting-holy-names-while-doing-worldly-duties-generate-any-punya-karma/9584#9584)

[Biological origins of life - Chandogya Upanishad](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12099/biological-origins-of-life-chandogya-upanishad/12100#12100)

[Is marijuana still sacred?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4051/is-marijuana-still-sacred/11843#11843)

[Does attachment and love coexist?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11501/does-attachment-and-love-coexist/11502#11502)

[Evolution of Earth - Yoga Vashishtha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/evolution-of-earth-yoga-vashishtha/12105#12105)

**Five Hardest Answers**

[Differences between Advaita & Vishishtadvaita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12272/differences-between-advaita-vishishtadvaita/12317#12317)

[How castes were produced in India?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11511/how-castes-were-produced-in-india/11515#11515)

[How can a person die if soul never leaves the body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12184/how-can-a-person-die-if-soul-never-leaves-the-body/12187#12187)

[How to focus on third eye while meditating?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12094/how-to-focus-on-third-eye-while-meditating/12096#12096)

[Why does Makar Sankranti follow English calendar?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3132/why-does-makar-sankranti-follow-english-calendar/11987#11987)

Comment: I think you slightly misunderstood the purpose of my question.  It's about choosing your questions which are easiest or hardest for a typical reader to understand, i.e. most basic and most advanced.  I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Oh okay, let me edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

I actually asked all easy questions only.

- [Does lord Shiva smoke Chillum?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2229/93)
- [Who gave boon to Vikramaditya to live for 2000 years and why?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/who-gave-boon-to-vikramaditya-to-live-for-2000-years-and-why)
- [Are there any strong evidence that Hinduism religion is an ancient one?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2632/93)
- [Did mountains used to have wings?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/1962/93)
- [How did Ravana get the golden city of Lanka?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/372/93)
- [Who made Lord Hanuman immortal?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/1976/93)
- [Number 9 in Hindu mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/215/number-9-in-hindu-mythology) (*Need citation to the accepted answer*)
- [Was value of pi really defined in a sloka?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6777/was-value-of-pi-really-defined-in-a-sloka)
- [Are there other Brahmas and universes?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/593/are-there-other-brahmas)
- [Why one should worship God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/why-one-should-worship-god)
- [What are the seven curses said by the goddesses to Lord Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/885/93) (**Not answered yet**)

I don't know whether the following question qualifies on this site or not but I am still looking for the answer.

- [Who serves the young in a family?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7288/93)

Answer (score 2):

**Questions**

**Easy Questions**

> 1) [In what circumstances Yagnopavita must be changed?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5418/in-what-circumstances-a-yagnopavita-is-needed-to-be-changed)
>
> 2) [Why RV Book 2 Hymn 23 Verse 1 is not used for worshiping Ganapati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/why-is-rig-veda-book-2-hymn-23-verse-1-not-used-for-summoning-or-praying-to-shri)
>
> 3) [What is Shatpath Bramhana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/what-is-shathpatha-brahman)
>
> 4) [Why is kripacharya known as 'Samitinjaya'](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10146/why-is-kripacharya-refered-to-as-smaitinjaya)
>
> 5) [SandhyaVandan in Ashucha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9903/sandhyavandan-in-ashaucha%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8C%E0%A4%9A)

**Advanced Questions**

> 1) [What is Pauman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6749/what-is-pauman-is-it-stotra-or-method)
>
> 2) [Best Mudra for Meditation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6947/which-is-the-best-mudra-for-meditation-likely-to-help-in-concentration)
>
> 3) [Meaning of Wearing Yagnopavita and its disposal techniques](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/what-is-meaning-of-wearing-yagopavita-and-its-disposal-techniques)
>
> 4) [Importance of Soma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7968/importance-of-soma)
>
> 5) [How to do Prana Pratishta of Idols](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/how-to-do-prana-pratishtha-of-idols)
>
> 6) [Method for chaning veda and sutra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/is-there-any-method-to-change-your-veda-and-sutras) **(my favorite question)**
>
> 7) [What will happen after all atmans get moksha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10008/what-will-happen-when-all-atmans-get-moksha) **(Philosophical Paradox)**
>
> 8) [How to do Abhivadan in Sandhyavandana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10497/how-to-do-abhivadan-in-sandhyavandana)

There are more questions I want to add to the list!! but that's it for now.

---

**Answers**

**Easy Answers**

> 1) [Why is tulsi water provided as tirtha in temples](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9893/why-tulsi-water-is-provided-as-theertha-in-temples/9894#9894)
>
> 2) [Are Lord Shiva And Shankar Different?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/are-lord-shiva-and-lord-shankar-two-different-deities/2283#2283)
>
> 3) [Why didnt Urmila accompany Laxmana in Forest](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/why-did-not-urmila-accompany-lakshmana/2420#2420)
>
> 4) [What is purva Pakshin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11596/what-is-purva-paksha-according-to-hindu-scriptures/11599#11599)
>
> 5) [What is difference between Shruti and Smriti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8591/what-is-difference-between-shruti-and-smriti/11607#11607)
>
> 6) [Swayambhoova Shrinath Ji temple story](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12256/swayamnbhoova-shri-nathji-temple-story/12287#12287)
>
> 7) [What are pancharatra Texts](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12279/what-exactly-are-pancharatra-texts/12321#12321)

**Advanced Answers**

> 1) [What is difference between Sooktam Stotram Gyatri and Ashtakam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10892/what-is-the-difference-between-suktam-strotam-gayatri-and-ashtakam/10895#10895)
>
> 2) [What are hymns chanted for abhishekham](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2709/what-are-hymns-chanted-for-abhishekam/2722#2722)
>
> 3) [What can be authentic source of Shraddha Vidhi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9871/what-would-be-the-authentic-source-for-%C5%9Ar%C4%81ddha-vidhi/9872#9872)
>
> 4) [I am confused between two shlokas of BG](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8735/i-am-confused-between-two-shlokas-of-the-bhagvad-geeta-bg-9-23-bg-9-25/8742#8742)
>
> 5) [Is Jesus Avatar of Lord Vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-jesus-an-avatar-of-lord-vishnu/2241#2241)